# Prestashop 1.7 Order page different than other pages

Tags: header, prestashop, footer

I'm just working on my first PrestaShop site and i have encounter some strange behaviour.

Order page is different than other pages (there is no menu, header background is different colour, there is no footer).

I probably could tweak some CSS and .tpl files, but i think that there have to be simple way.

P.S. I'm using classic template.

Answer (score 0):

This is default layout for Order Page for not having menu in Header and have different footer unlike other pages in Prestashop 1.7.

Comment: Ok thnx for the answer, but is there any way to change it?